# Change Background Image in Flutter according to theme

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have different pages, and one FloatingActionBar, whensoever I am clicking on it, the theme of the application is getting changed. But I also want to change the background image of the app. How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "theme of the application", do you mean the "themeMode" property of MaterialApp?

Comment: I am using one button to switch between two modes. like between light and dark mode. Along with this, I also want to change the background image of the app according to light and dark mode.

Comment: You can define your own light&dark themes (class ThemeData), which includes attributes like primaryColor. Then in your UI you should be able to get the primaryColor of the CURRENT theme like this: "Theme.of(context).primaryColor"